# perl script called from PHP generates file with zero bytes size

Tags: php, perl

I am calling external Perl script to convert DXF file to SVG, but when script is called from PHP the output SVG file is always 0 bytes. When executing the same command from terminal the output SVG file is OK.

I am executing command via PHP system() and also tried exec() and popen() but I always have the same result.

dxf2svg.pl perl script source code: http://pastebin.com/fE2BcUqE

command that I am executing:

```
perl /path/dxf2svg.pl "/path_to_dxf/file.dxf" ">/output_path/file.dxf"
```

Outup path is writable to PHP user, so this is not the problem.

Comment: It's fact that the problem is in php script. Can you show it too?

Comment: One guess is that your weird open statement with included `MODE` is messing things up. I.e. that PHP turns it into redirection, and overwrites the file after the perl script is done. However, that *should* cause your perl script to die since it cannot open to a file name which is an undefined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12037/discussion-between-tlp-and-primoz-rome) it was discovered that the line

```
open (WRITECSS, ">output.css")or die("error in Writing CSSFile");
```

Was the culprit. Since running the script from the command line created a file with the wrong write permissions, the script died at this statement. Since errors were not returned to PHP, the error was silent.

The solution was to `chmod` the output CSS file.

Debugging was done by redirecting `STDERR` from perl to a file, and adding the error reporting variable `$!` to the `die` statement:

```
open STDERR, ">>", "somefile" or die $!;
open (WRITECSS, ">output.css")or die("error in Writing CSSFile: $!");
```

Comment: Original perl script had this line as `open (WRITECSS, ">output.svg")`. I just changed the script so that I can supply the output file. I will try the suggested changes and confirm the result! UPDATE: the same result as before! The output file is still Zero Bytes :(. Tried the command from terminal and it works well as before! From PHP the same situation!

Comment: @PrimozRome You can just check the PHP error log (apache?) and see if you find those errors there. But you should be aware that not using hard coded `open` modes is a very bad idea, and also a security risk. Someone could give the argument `"| rm -rf /"` and then you are screwed.

Comment: Regarding the security issue, thanks for the notes, I will make sure this doesn't happen. Nothing in Apache error log, access log looks fine.

Comment: changed Perl code to  `open (WRITEFILE, ">", $ARGV[1])or die("error in Writing WriteFile");` and changed my command to:  `'perl dxf2svg.pl "/path_to_dxf/p16uka04111fhu3r811971gtbgj41.dxf" "/svg_out_path/p16uka04111fhu3r811971gtbgj41.svg"' `

Comment: Try reverting back to the original, hard coded, open and see if that helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12037/discussion-between-tlp-and-primoz-rome)