# Use a linux command in a Perl programm, and use Perl through php exec()

Tags: php, linux, perl, system, exec

I'm creating a system that allow me to create users automatically after an inscription. In this way, i've made a Perl script that generate a random password, crypt it with "mkpasswd" and then create an user with "useradd", after that user-infos are sended to a database.

I've search documentation, and i've try to use the php exec function to call the Perl program.

```
$command = "/server/backoffice/scripts/usercreation.pl $username";
exec($command, $result);
print_r($result);
```

The usercreation.pl script work fine in a terminal, but for a unknown reason, it just not work from php, nothing happen, i know that the problem come from the useradd syntax or if not it come from the useradd command. The error value returned is 255 <=> 0xff <=> -1 .

I think the problem come from the --password option of useradd, in fact, this option use mkpasswd and maybe it could disturb the shell or something else like that :p

The complete useradd command used by the Perl program:

```
system("/usr/sbin/useradd $username -m -d $home --expiredate $expire --shell $shell --gid $gid --password $c_password");
```

**EDIT:**
The usercreation.pl file on pastebin (has been truncated to the part we are investigate):
http://pastebin.com/DgFdndXf

The php one :
http://pastebin.com/pQhADNzg

The web server used is nginx/0.7.65.

The version of php used is PHP 5.3.3-1.

```
uname -a
```

`Linux openco 2.6.35-32-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 5 19:35:26 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux`

Thanks for all!

Comment: Does the PHP run from a web server?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10852071/725418) for a way to debug your perl script execution from within PHP.

Comment: The error does not come from Perl, but from the PHP interpretation of ...

Comment: @torr Do you run the perl script in the shell with the same user as runs the PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useradd` must be run as root, so you will need `sudo` to specify that nginx can run your script as root.

Be extremely careful with this stuff; make sure you sanitize user names and escape your command properly as well using `escapeshellarg()`.

Comment: So, it would work if i add `www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd` in /etc/sudoers and if i change $command to "sudo ".$command ?

Comment: Now, the error returned is 127 <=> 0x7f, i've also changed the $command in the Perl program to `sudo useradd [...]`

Comment: @DaveNull Actually ... the `sudoers` file should give permission to run the Perl script as root, not `useradd` itself.

Comment: I've made the changes, `exec("sudo ".$command, $result)`, useradd is called wthout sudo. www-data is no allowed to execute the Perl script as root. But, it do not change the error returned.

Comment: Well, then I'm out of ideas I'm afraid :-/

Comment: I think that the error come from the useradd command, in fact, i written this Perl program, then i know that he stop the execution just  when the useradd command is used. It's really weird, cause it works perfectly in a shell. So maybe, the error happen when php and perl discuss of the $username ? I'm gonna pastbin all the codes

Comment: I've tried to execute the php file from cli, `$username = $_SESSION['username']` change in `$username = "stack"` cause cookies and session are meaningless from cli. And everything worked fine.

Comment: It could also be that the perl script forces an interactive shell. Just a hunch.

Comment: It couldn't, when i execute it in a shell there's no interaction. Moreover, useradd isn't a interactive command.

Comment: @DaveNull btw, you removed the `sudo` from perl script and restarted (not just reload) apache right?